# Can I use IDENTITY_INSERT in a cursor on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, identity-column

I have the following code:

```
 declare c cursor for
            select
                id_user_V3
                ,device_type
                ,4
                ,notfication_mode
                ,t1.device_token
                ,registration_date
                ,rank
                ,1
            from audiv2.dbo.mya_webservice_device_token t1
                join migr.asoc_V2_glb_user t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id_user_V2

        open c
        fetch next from c into @id_user_v3,@type,@application_id,@notiffication,@device_tooken,@creation_date,@rang,@status
        while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
            begin

                set @device_id = (ISNULL((SELECT MAX(id_device) FROM usr_device)+1,1))

                SET IDENTITY_INSERT usr_device ON

                insert into usr_device values
                (
                    @device_id
                    ,@id_user_v3
                    ,@type
                    ,@application_id
                    ,@notiffication
                    ,@device_tooken
                    ,@creation_date
                    ,@rang
                    ,@status
                )
                SET IDENTITY_INSERT usr_device OFF

                fetch next from c into @id_user_v3,@type,@application_id,@notiffication,@device_tooken,@creation_date,@rang,@status
            end

        close c
        deallocate c
```

The error I get is :

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'usr_device' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By reading the error message again or searching on this error message? There are *two* conditions required for inserting an identity value. "a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON". Well, you've turned on `IDENTITY_INSERT`...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I put IDENTITY_INSERT usr_device ON before inserting in table

Comment: But as the error message says, and as I highlighted, there are **two** conditions you have to meet. You've met one of them (turning on `IDENTITY_INSERT`) - you *also* have to meet the other one - use a column list.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thank you. Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention all the column names explicity in the INSERT clause

insert into usr_device (col1, col2,...) values